# qt gui how to get progress from another class

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a Qt-GUI class 'Widget' where I've created QProgressButton. 
'Widget' has instance of class 'Engine'. Function Start() in 'Engine' make many computations in large loop. How can I update this progress bar from Engine? Should I use QThread?

Comment: If `Engine` class does some heavy processing that causes the GUI to freeze, then you should move it to a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use multithreading. Make pointer in 'Engine' class, sth like this:

```
QProgressBar* ReferenceBar;
```

You also need to create setter in class 'Engine' for this reference:

```
void setBar(QProgressBar* bar){
     ReferenceBar = bar;
}
```

In GUI you must directly set the progress bar:

```
instanceOfEngine = new Engine();
...
instanceOfEngine->setBar(progressBar);
```

And activate updating the bar in your 'Engine' loop:

```
Start(){
...
for(int i=0; i < x; i++){
     //computing....
     ReferenceBar->setValue(100*i/(x-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your object of the class `Engine` on the heap and move it to a new thread in order to prevent it from blocking main thread and the UI.

This can be done like:

```
engine = new Engine();
QThread * th = new QThread();
engine->moveToThread(th);

QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(started()),engine,SLOT(OnStarted()));
QObject::connect(th,SIGNAL(finished()),engine,SLOT(OnFinished()));

th->start();
```

Your initialization and termination tasks in the class `Engine` should be done in `OnStarted()` and `OnFinished()` slots respectively.

You should use a signal in the class `Engine` to notify the progress bar in your user interface of the value for the progress. You can emit the signal with the appropriate value in your function containing the loop or in a timer  in certain intervals. The latter is better because it prevents from emitting the signal too much if the loop is repeated too frequently.

The signal is like:

```
void progressChanged(int val);
```

You should also connect the `progressChanged(int)` signal to the `setValue(int value)` slot of the `QProgressBar`.

And the last point is that you should not call the functions of `Engine` directly when it is in an other thread. The correct way is defining the functions as a slots and connecting signals to that slots and emitting a signal when you want to call a function.